# Unable to write the logs to the console and log file using spring boot 1.5.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using the **Spring boot 1.5.3** release and for logs, I am using the default spring boot logging. 
I didn't add any extra dependencies for this and added the below properties to my application.properties file.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=info

logging.level.com.mypackage.service.*=debug
logging.level.root=info
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M - %msg%n"
```

But the spring logs are writing to the console and application logs are not writing to the console and **"System.out.println"** also not printing in the console while deploying the application in tomcat.

Kindly provide me how to resolve this issue and print system out statements.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard is not needed there, this will be sufficient

```
logging.level.com.mypackage.service=debug
```

Remember that if you have your `root` on info level, then no debug logs will come whatsoever, so debug logs from com.mypackage.service will be suppressed.

Comment: Still, the same problem persisted.

Comment: private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log LOGGER = org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(DataExceptionControllerAdvice.class);
    private static final org.jboss.logging.Logger LOGGER1 = Logger.getLogger(DataExceptionControllerAdvice.class);
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER2 = org.jboss.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataExceptionControllerAdvice.class);
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER3 =
            org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(DataExceptionControllerAdvice.class);

Comment: I tried above ways but no use. Logger is not printing to the console

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the starter loggin dependency. It's included by default in all the spring starters projects but I cannot see your pom so I'm not sure about your pom configuration.

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>`